# Load data into chart through sequelizejs from mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js, c3.js

I have used this [chart](/http://c3js.org/) library but I don't know how can load data into it. I have never load data from mysql to chart. So I don't know what is best practice ...

**So I have in MySQL table Orders rows like:**

```
id | price | kind | orderdate
-----------------------------
1  |  35   | 2    | 2013-01-01
2  |  30   | 1    | 2013-01-01
3  |  25   | 3    | 2013-01-01
4  |  15   | 2    | 2013-01-01
```

**Further c3js loading data in format like:**

```
   columns: [
        ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05'],
        ['kind1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150],
        ['kind2', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150],
        ['kind3', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150],
    ]
```

So I have created dates array like below `['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05']` and I need for every this date, number of rows where example kind=1.
But I don't know how MySQL query must looks like... Do I need query for each date in my dates array?
Or Is there better way ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to extract the data from the table on the server and get it into javascript on the browser. How to do that depends on what you're using, e.g. PHP, but the query could be something like this:

```
select   orderdate, kind, sum(price) as total
from     #orders
where    orderdate between '1 Jan 2013' and '10 jan 2013'
group by orderdate, kind
```

My preference would be to expose the data via a JSON API so you get the data from a url (paraterized with from & to dates) in this format:

```
[
{'orderdate':'2013-01-01', 'kind': 1, 'total': 30},
{'orderdate':'2013-01-01', 'kind': 2, 'total': 50},
{'orderdate':'2013-01-01', 'kind': 3, 'total': 25},
{'orderdate':'2013-01-02', 'kind': 1, 'total': 30},
{'orderdate':'2013-01-02', 'kind': 2, 'total': 20},
{'orderdate':'2013-01-02', 'kind': 3, 'total': 23}
]
```

Then to "transpose" the data into the columns you need:

```
['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05'],
['kind1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150],
['kind2', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150],
['kind3', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150],
```

The first column is straight-forward as you have the from & to dates.

To build up rows 2, 3, 4, assuming you know the list of kinds:

```
for each kind:
 create an array, eg: var data = ['kind1'];
 initialise a sum variable, eg: var sum = 0;
 for each date (in the correct order):
  loop through the array, if the date & the kind match, add to the sum variable
 add the sum to the array, eg: data.push(sum);
```

That should do it?